# With R, how to delete duplicate rows and to keep the minimum starting date and maximum ending date by duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I got a data frame with identical values for each variables, but with starting and ending dates different.

I wish to reduce the data frame by deleting the duplicate rows, without considering starting dates or ending dates. Then I need to keep for each rows as value, for the starting date variable, the minimum given for the duplicated row, and to do the same with the maximum. Note that NA value can be provide by the variables Date_Begin and Date_End.

I know how to do it with a loop. I am looking for a better solution, maybe using the packages plyr/dyplr whom I am not yet very confident with.

see below what I use currently. I am sure that a better "pipeline" is possible but did not success to make it so far.

## my data.frame before :

```
`head(dat)
id1 id2 id3 Date_Begin Date_End
FR1 1     A   2019-12-16 2019-12-18
FR1 1     A   2019-12-19 2020-01-16
FR2 3     B   2020-01-07 2020-01-10
FR2 4     C   2020-01-12 2020-02-03
FR1 5     A   2020-01-17 2020-02-03
FR3 6     D   2020-01-22 2020-02-03`
```

## the loop which is working but probably not the best option

```
`dat$key <- paste(dat$id1, dat$id2, dat$id3, sep = "_")
dat2 <- distinct(data.frame(id1 = dat$id1, id2 = dat$id2, id3 = dat$id3, Date_Begin = NA, Date_End = NA, key = dat$key))
dat2 <- data.frame(lapply(dat2, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
N <- dim(dat2)[1]
for(i in 1 : N)
    {
    x <- which(dat$key == dat2$key[i])
    y <- which.min(dat$Date_Begin[x])
    z <- which.max(dat$Date_End[x])
    dat2$Date_Begin[i] <- ifelse(length(y) > 0, as.character(dat$Date_Begin[x][y]), NA)
    dat2$Date_End[i] <- ifelse(length(z) > 0, as.character(dat$Date_End[x][z]), NA)
    }
dat <- dat2 ; rm(dat2)
dat$Date_Begin <- parse_date(dat$Date_Begin, approx = TRUE, default_tz = "UTC")
dat$Date_End <- parse_date(dat$Date_End, approx = TRUE, default_tz = "UTC")
dat$key <- NULL`
```

## my data.frame after :

```
`head(dat)
id1 id2 id3 Date_Begin Date_End
FR1 1     A   2019-12-16 2020-01-16
FR2 3     B   2020-01-07 2020-01-10
FR2 4     C   2020-01-12 2020-02-03
FR1 5     A   2020-01-17 2020-02-03
FR3 6     D   2020-01-22 2020-02-03`
```

I made several tries like this below, with dplyr, but did not found the right solution.

```
`
dat <- dat %>%
group_by(id1, id2, id3) %>% 
slice(which.max(Date_End)
`
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- readr::read_table2("id1 id2 id3 Date_Begin Date_End
FR1 1     A   2019-12-16 2019-12-18
FR1 1     A   2019-12-19 2020-01-16
FR2 3     B   2020-01-07 2020-01-10
FR2 4     C   2020-01-12 2020-02-03
FR1 5     A   2020-01-17 2020-02-03
FR3 6     D   2020-01-22 2020-02-03")

group_by(df, id1, id2, id3) %>% 
  summarise(Date_Begin = min(Date_Begin), Date_End = max(Date_End)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   id1     id2 id3   Date_Begin Date_End  
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <date>     <date>    
#> 1 FR1       1 A     2019-12-16 2020-01-16
#> 2 FR1       5 A     2020-01-17 2020-02-03
#> 3 FR2       3 B     2020-01-07 2020-01-10
#> 4 FR2       4 C     2020-01-12 2020-02-03
#> 5 FR3       6 D     2020-01-22 2020-02-03
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: do we have to list all the columns? is there a way to simply say "take current dataframe, check if we have duplicates in column X and if that's the case keep the row with the smallest value in column Y, without specifying id1, id2, etc.. ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```r
dat %>% 
  group_by(id1, id2, id3) %>% 
  summarise(min(Date_Begin),max(Date_End))
```

Comment: do we have to list all the columns? is there a way to simply say "take current dataframe, check if we have duplicates in column X and if that's the case keep the row with the smallest value in column Y, without specifying id1, id2, etc.. ?